# trying to add an image in html

Tags: html, hyperlink, image, href, src

I've just added a new widget to my blog, using a label-search url to pull up specific posts. This is working very nicely.

However, I want to add an image next to the link, and this is *not* working. I'm getting a nasty blue question mark on the page instead of my photo. I've looked up all the attributes I'm using and I think my syntax is OK, so I'm stumped. Would somebody please point out what I've done wrong?

thanks

MM

```
<!-- Navigation2 tabs start -->
<div id='georgetownlist'>
<a    
href="http://s1275.photobucket.com/user/MaddyMarcel/media/DCgraffiti_zps23603274.jpg.html"     
imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;"><img 
src="http://s1275.photobucket.com/user/MaddyMarcel/media/DCgraffiti_zps23603274.jpg.html" 
alt="DC" border="0" height="40" /> 
<a href="http://proustscookies.blogspot.com/search/label/Georgetown%20favorites"    
class="georgetowntab" title="Georgetown favorites">MY GEORGETOWN</a>
</a></div>
<!-- Navigation2 tabs end -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You have .html on the end of your src attributes.  The image source should end in .jpg, not .jpg.html.

```
src="http://s1275.photobucket.com/user/MaddyMarcel/media/DCgraffiti_zps23603274.jpg.html
```

should be

```
src="http://i1275.photobucket.com/albums/y449/MaddyMarcel/DCgraffiti_zps23603274.jpg
```

Comment: Won't work since that's not a valid link. Photobucket does not support hotlinking, you [OP] should upload your image on your website and link it as `path/to/image.jpg` or host it somewhere else. In addition, html also supports .gif, .png and .bmp

Comment: Totally right ... I took off the .html, that's necessary but not sufficient.  Switched hosting to Picassa and that worked.  Thanks!